# Convert a string field with pennies into a dollar amount with 2 decimal places in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have a field in a table as nvarchar(10), which is used to store a value in pennies. For example, $23.50 is stored as "2350".

I need to return this value to the program in Money format. How would I do that in the Select statement?

Comment: are there always 2 decimal places in that string? i.e. can you always assume that the last 2 digits are cents?

Comment: I'm guessing this was stored as NVARCHAR to support different currency formats?

Comment: It comes from the processor in that format, and yes there are always 2 decimal places.

Comment: I ended up doing this: convert(money,convert(money,penny_field)/100.0)
Seems to work ok. May not be the most efficient, but it doesn't need to be in this case.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT CAST (IntAmount / 100.00 as MONEY)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 cast(cast (pennies as numeric(16,2))/100 as money)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select convert(money, field/100, 0) from table
```

Comment: No. This will round the result. 101 comes out as 1.00 instead of 1.01. If you divide field by 100.0 instead, then you're OK.

Comment: I did not see that the pennies were being removed.  Good catch.